# Timber - list categories and their posts

Tags: wordpress, categories, timber

I have a CPT ('vehicles') with custom taxonomy ('vehicles_category')

I have 4 categories (construction, road, waste, other) with numerous posts assigned to each of these categories.

I'm trying to list out each category with the posts assigned to them underneath so..

```
Construction
     Post 1    
     Post 2     
     etc
Road
     Post 6
     Post 9
     etc
```

Been battling with this.

I have this to get the posts...

```
$context['vehicles'] = Timber::get_posts([
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'vehicles',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'paged' => $paged,
]);
```

and this to get the categories...

```
$context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('vehicle_category');
$context['posts'] = $context['vehicles'];
```

So far i have this in my twig file...

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% if category.count >= 1 %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{site.url}}/vehicles/{{ category.slug }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it only outputs the categories as I'm missing the bit to output the posts but everything I try doesn't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Ok, really overthought this so stepped back a bit.

```
$context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('vehicle_category');
```

vehicle_category is my custom taxonomy.

```
{% for category in categories %}
    <h1>{{category.name}}</h1>

    <div class="c-vehicle--list">

                {% for post in category.posts %}
                    <div class="c-vehicle--list__item">

                            <a href="{{ site.url }}/vehicles/{{ post.slug }}" title="{{ post.title }}">
                                <img src="{{TimberImage(post.vehicle_image).src('postMedium')}}" alt="{{ post.title }}">
                                <span>{{ post.title }}</span>
                                <span>{{ post.terms('vehicle_category') | join(', ') }}</span>
                            </a>

                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

So simply loop out the categories in my custom taxonomy and then list the posts `post in category.post` associated with that category.